# Skipping rows when iterating through NSMutableArray in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, loops

I got this code in my UITableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell2";
    GamesInfoTableViewCell *cell = (GamesInfoTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    GameInfo *gameInfoObject;

    gameInfoObject =[LiveGamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([gameInfoObject.GameTime  isEqual: @"FT"] | ([gameInfoObject.GameTime rangeOfString:@":"].location != NSNotFound)){
     -------------->  What to do here? <----------------------------

    }
    cell.backgroundColor = TABLECOLOR;

    cell.homeTeamLabel.textColor = TEXT;
    cell.awayTeamLabel.textColor = TEXT;
    cell.gameTimeLabel.textColor = TEXT;

    cell.liveButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1675447.png"]; //Load the green image
    cell.awayTeamLabel.text = gameInfoObject.AwayTeam;
    cell.homeTeamLabel.text = gameInfoObject.HomeTeam;
    cell.homeTeamScoreLabel.text = gameInfoObject.HomeScore;
    cell.awayTeamScoreLabel.text = gameInfoObject.AwayScore;
    cell.gameTimeLabel.text = gameInfoObject.GameTime;

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;

}
```

So i have a NSMutableArray that contains some objects. And i would only like to populate the table cells with some of the objects. The If statement checks that and if its true then i would like it to go on with the next object/row in the array. I have tried a couple of things but neither did work. Is the only solution to make another NSMutableArray so i can store the ones i want to populate there and then iterate through that one?

Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your code : if ([gameInfoObject.GameTime  isEqual: @"FT"] | ([gameInfoObject.GameTime rangeOfString:@":"].location != NSNotFound)){ it should be if ([gameInfoObject.GameTime  isEqual: @"FT"] || ([gameInfoObject.GameTime rangeOfString:@":"].location != NSNotFound)){

Comment: Is the Or checking inside the if condition (sorry for the poor formatting ). Only one | is for bitwise operations.

Comment: I get what you are saying, the code works when i try it i think its strange know it should be two of them..

Comment: In most cases it should work like that (bitwise or). http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bools-sharp-corners/ here is a great article about BOOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key issue that prevents you from coding this up with a conditional inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is that the `row` from the index path represents a cumulative value of all items that have not been skipped. Hence you need to consider all values in your array in deciding what to print.

> Is the only solution to make another `NSMutableArray` so i can store the ones i want to populate there and then iterate through that one?

This would be a good solution. This is much better than an alternative of traversing the array from the beginning each time, counting the matching objects until you skip `row-1` objects, and taking the next one.

Another alternative is building a translation table - i.e. an array of indexes that maps a row to the index in the original `NSMutableArray`. You can build this table in the method that supplies the row count to your `UITableView`, and keep it until the next refresh.

Suppose your `NSMutableArray` looks like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
N Y Y N N Y N Y N N
```

Top row shows element index. `Y` is the item you want to keep; `N` is the item you don't want to show. Your row count method returns 4 (the number of `Y`s), and builds a table that looks like this:

```
0 1 2 3
1 2 5 7
```

The top row is the index of the index array. The bottom row is the index into the original array. Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code needs to pick

```
gameInfoObject =[LiveGamesArray objectAtIndex:translation[indexPath.row]];
```

For row 0, `translation[indexPath.row]` is 1; for row 1, translation is 2; for row 2, translation is 5, and for row 3 it is 7.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should, you are filtering the array in cellForRowAtIndexPath, which will be called many times. So what I would recommend is to make the array prepared before you load the table.

Answer (score 0):

as you say "So i have a NSMutableArray that contains some objects. And i would only like to populate the table cells with some of the objects."so there hould be ideally two arrays, 1.LiveGamesArray, 2. create a new filter array like this:

```
NSMutableArray * filterArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (GameInfo *gameInfoObject in LiveGamesArray)//can use predicate also
{
@autorelease{
    if ([gameInfoObject.GameTime  isEqual: @"FT"] || ([gameInfoObject.GameTime rangeOfString:@":"].location != NSNotFound)) {
        [filterArray addObject:gameInfoObject];
    }
}
}
```

3.use this  filterArray in all data source/ delegate method of your tableview.
hope it will help you.